# ti.draggable android module doesn't work on intel cpu

Tags: android

I've got error on Samsung - Galaxy Tab 3 (GT-P5210) 4.2.2 (Intel Atom Z2560 1600 Mhz) from app using ti.draggable:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library:
>   load_library(linker.cpp:761): not a valid ELF executable:
>   /data/app-lib/sc.gm.sm-1/libti.draggable.so   at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)   at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)     at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.loadExternalModules(V8Runtime.java:114)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:81)
>     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:175)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:109)

At the same time on Samsung - Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (GT-P5110) it's okey, it has CPU TI OMAP4430 1000 Mhz

Does some know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ti.draggable has an x86 shared object included. If the application included this shared object, you shouldn't be seeing the issue that you are currently reporting. [Here](http://cl.ly/2y1z2F132P0o) is the link to the archive with x86 libs. Since this is a native library, there can be issues in running on a platform if the corresponding .so is absent.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the library does not contain native module (.so) for x86 architecture or it wasn't included in to your .apk. Unfortunately, I haven't worked with titanium. Try to specify some 'build targets' options etc...